# Emacs does not create new windows for new buffers

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am very new to emacs. I just started using it. After a fresh install of spacemacs on my macbook when I opened a file from neo tree or command line it used to appear in a new window. Now it's opening in the same window and the file that was already open gets hidden. I don't know what I did wrong. I even reinstalled spacemacs from scratch but it is of no use.

Also, I can't find a way to open a file in a new frame and close it in the frame that it's already in.

Comment: I highly recommend Emacs tutorial. When I decided to use Emacs as my main IDE, I went 3 times in a row through tutorial. It pays off. (And you will understand what's going on with all those buffers, frames etc. and how to manage them)

Answer (score 2):

> it used to appear in a new window. Now it's opening in the same
>   window and the file that was already open gets hidden.

I don't know about spacemacs, but for Emacs generally it's completely
normal when visiting a file for the current window to be re-used.

The `pop-up-windows` user option would affect this some of the time,
but that's non-nil by default, so you probably have that enabled
already?

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `pop-up-windows` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Naturally there are other rules and settings around this behaviour
(which is very flexible), so I would also recommend reading about it
in the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Window Choice`

You can use the command `find-file-other-window` to make Emacs display
the buffer in the 'other' window (creating a new window if necessary).

This is usually bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> but
spacemacs may be different?

Refer to: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Pop Up Window`

> Also, I can't find a way to open a file in a new frame and close it
>   in the frame that it's already in.

Similarly to the above, by default:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> calls `find-file-other-frame`
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> calls `delete-frame`

Refer to: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Creating Frames`